# Is it possible to bulk migrate all deprecated instances of a gutenberg block?

Tags: block-editor

I wrote a plugin which defines a gutenberg block. After using this block in posts, I've changed its definition inside my plugin, so now I have a "deprecated" entry in the block configuration containing "migrate" function. I can open and save each post containing this block and the migration is applied.

Is it possible to do this for all posts automatically? If yes then how? (in order to get rid of the "deprecated" code in block configuration)

Comment: `registerBlockType` config object has a `deprecated` property that is meant to do this. When the post editor is opened those blocks will be "transformed" into the new structure if there is a matching deprecation. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-deprecation/). Otherwise if you would want to change all posts content in a single run I guess you would need to loop the database.

Comment: The way I got round this was to add an activation function to my plugin that does this - you can use `has_block()` against the content then do what you need - when I had updated the code I deactivated the plugin and re-activated it. Pain in the ****